# Url.Action alternate in razor page view model class

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

What can be used to get the URL of the page which is in this path of the project `<website>/Pages/Account/Logout.cshtml`

This is using view model razor pages and not mvc controller/action

When I use `Url.Action("/Account/Logout", new { logoutId = ogoutId });` it says cannot resolve action `/Account/Logout`

Answer (score 16):

In Razor Pages, you could use @Url.Page.

```
<a href="@Url.Page("/Account/Logout",new { logoutId = 1 })">Logout</a>
```

Or use `asp-page` directly,see more usage [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-2.2#asp-page).

```
<a asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-logoutId ="1">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Thanks, will this automatically return the correct url if there is a custom route config?

Comment: It will. If you set your custom route like `@page "/Test/{logoutId:int}"`in Logout.cshtml,it will return `/Test/1`